# Ruby on Rails: Downloading files with multiple dots in filename (uploaded using Carrierwave)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The view:

```
<%= link_to File.basename(attachment.attachment.url), "/uploads/#{attachment.id}/#{File.basename(attachment.attachment.url)}" %>
```

The controller:

```
# ...
  def download
    path = "#{Rails.root}/uploads/"+ params[:id] + "/"+ params[:basename] +"."+ params[:extension]

    send_file path, :x_sendfile=>true
  end
# ...
```

The route:

```
match "/uploads/:id/:basename.:extension", :controller => "attachments", :action => "download", :conditions => { :method => :get }
```

The error is get is:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/uploads/38/Screen_shot_2012-02-18_at_2.20.49_PM.png"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
match "/uploads/:id/:filename.:extension", :controller => "attachments", :action => "download", :constraints => { :filename => /[^\/]+/ },  :conditions => { :method => :get }
```

Thanks to forker I was led to this blog: http://coding-journal.com/rails-3-routing-parameters-with-dots/

Comment: Awesome. This saved me..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
match "/uploads/:id/:filename", :controller => "attachments", :action => download, :requirements => { :filename => /.*/ }
```

via [this blog post](http://flip.netzbeben.de/2008/07/rails-routes-and-special-characters-like-dots/)

Comment: Thanks but this did not work for me. However, I found my answer due to the blog post you linked in this answer.

Comment: You're welcome! That's exactly how I usually find solutions :)